# Set logo size in Firebase UI

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Is there anyway to set the size of the logo in Firebase UI so it doesn't completely fill the view?

```
AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build()
                    ))
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)
                    .setLogo(R.mipmap.icon_hero_image)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN
```

Comment: Wow Frank van Puffelen just editted my post, such an honor :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the following in your styles.xml file, this will work with the setLogo method. This will style the logo so add/change items in the style however you would like:

```
<style name="FirebaseUI.AuthMethodPicker.Logo">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:padding">24dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm also having this problem, although that .xml snippit doesn't seem to have an affect on the view.

Comment: @aedgar777 have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I have not. I think I am going to end up just using the full Firebase SDK Authentication method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth